# Connected components of quotient space.

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces

Let $\mathcal{R}$ be an equivalent relation over $X$ such that $\forall x\in X$, its class $[x]$ is included in some connected component of $X$. Show that the connected components of $X/\mathcal{R}$ are the images of the connected components of $X$ via the quotient map.

So far, denoting $\pi : X\to X/\mathcal{R}$ the quotient map, I've proved that, given a connected component $C_x$ of $X$, then $\pi(C_x)\subset C_{[x]}$. This is because $x\in [x]$ and the continuous image of a connected set is also connected. But I don't see the other inclusion, could you please tell me any hint?

Comment: Suppose $x$ and $y$ are in different components, so there are disjoint closed-and-open $U,V$ with $x\in U$, $y\in V$. Show that $U$ (and similarly $V$) is $\mathcal R$-saturated: if $z\in U$ then $[z]$ is contained in $U$. Use this to show that $\pi(U)$ and $\pi(V)$ form a closed-and-open partition of  $\pi : X\to X/\mathcal R$.

Comment: A clopen set is the union of connected components. Keep that in mind and re-read @Mirko's comment.

Comment: I thought of $C_x$ and $C_y$ as $U$ and $V$ (they would be both closed, which is also valid), but I cannot guarantee that $\pi(U)\cup\pi(V)=X/\mathcal{R}$.

Comment: A clopen set is the union of connected components but the converse is not necessarily true. Therefore, the idea of taking the union of the rest of the connected components (which is the other that I had) could be not right. @DanielFischer

Comment: @Mirko what do you mean by a partition of $\pi : X\to X/\mathcal R$? I should find a partition of $C_{[x]}$.

Comment: I copied and pasted, and didn't carefully read/edit it: It should have been "a partition of $X/\mathcal R$ " rather than "a partition of $\pi : X\to X/\mathcal R$". I also assume $U\cup V = X$ so, $U,V$ form a partition of $X$. Take any $[x]$, then $x$ is in either $U$ or $V$. Say $x\in U$. Note that $[x]$ cannot intersect both $U$ and $V$ since that would result in a partition of $[x]$. So $[x]\subseteq U$, and $[x]\in\pi(U)$. We do not assume $U=C_x$ for some $x$, rather (one could prove that) $U=\cup\{C_a:a\in A\}$ for a suitable $A\subset X$. Note $\pi(U)$ is open since $\pi^{-1}\pi(U)=U$.

Comment: We have $\pi^{-1}(\pi(U)) = U$ because $U$ is a union of equivalence classes. $$U = \bigcup \bigl\{ [z] : [z] \cap U \neq \varnothing\bigr\}.$$

Comment: Ok, but, where's the contradiction in having a partition of $X/\mathcal R$? I didn't assume that it was connected. I guess it's a partition of the connected component of $[x]$, but it's not clear, should I use $U\cap C_{[x]}$ and $V\cap C_{[x]}$?

Comment: it shows that $[y]$ does not belong to $C_{[x]}$. You already proved that $\pi(C_x)\subseteq C_{[x]}$, and you need to prove the other direction, that $C_{[x]}\subseteq \pi(C_x)$, and the partition you get for $X/\mathcal R$ should help you do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $q:X\to Y$ is a quotient map with the property that the fiber of each $y\in Y$ is contained in some component of $X$. Then, it maps each component of $X$ to a component of $Y$. Indeed, if $C$ is a component of $X$, then $q(C)$ is contained in a component $D$ of $Y$. Moreover, $q^{-1}(D)$ is connected. Seeking contradiction, assume $q^{-1}(D)=U\cup V$ where $U$ and $V$ are non-empty disjoint open subsets of $q^{-1}(D)$, then $q(U)$ and $q(V)$ are non-empty disjoint subsets of $D$ with $D=q(U)\cup q(V)$. We claim that $q(U)$ and $q(V)$ are open subsets of $D$. Note that if $x\in q^{-1}(q(U))$, then $q(x)=q(a)$ for some $a\in U$. But, $q(x)=q(a)=y\in D$ (as $q$ is onto) and hence $a,x\in q^{-1}(y)\subset U$ as $q^{-1}(y)$ is contained in a connected subset. Thus, $U=q^{-1}(q(U))$ and similarly $V=q^{-1}(q(V))$. Since $q^{-1}(D)$ is a closed subset, $q:q^{-1}(D)\to q(q^{-1}(D)=D$ is a quotient map which implies that $q(U)$ and $q(V)$ are open, a contradiction.

Now, $q(C)\subset D$ and thus $C\subset q^{-1}(q(C))\subset q^{-1}(D)$. So, $C=q^{-1}(D)$ and hence $q(C)=D$.

Answer (score 1):

It is easier to think about connectedness in terms of the relative topology. You can restrict the domain $X$ to $\pi^{-1}(C_{[x]})$ and assume that the quotient is connected (equal to $C_{[x]}$). Let us show that the domain is also connected.

Take a nonempty clopen set $F \subset X$. Since clopen sets are unions of connected components, the hypothesis imply that $F$ is the union of equivalence classes. But then, this means that $B = \pi(F)$ is clopen. Just notice that $F = \pi^{-1}(B)$. But since the codomain is connected and $F$ is nonempty, $B = C_{[x]}$. But this means that $F = \pi^{-1}(C_{[x]}) = X$. Therefore, $X$ has only trivial clopen subsets. That is, $X$ is connected.

---

This proof is a bit difficult because of the first paragraph.

---

The quotient topology can be understood as a weaker topology over $X$, where the open sets are restricted to the "saturated ones". That is, the open sets in this weaker topology are the original open sets that are unions of fibers.

When you make the topology weaker, you reduce the number of closed sets and open sets. But the hypothesis warrants that **you do not reduce the number of clopen sets!!!** Because, in this case, the clopen sets are already unions of equivalence classes.